# Usuario ordena un diccionario en python

Tags: python, diccionarios

Estoy iniciando en python, y necesito hacer un programa donde se mostraran de forma aleatoria (random) los elementos de un diccionario, y luego el usuario tendrá que ordenarlos. El diccionario esta listo, pero no se me ocurre como hacer para que el usuario lo ordene.

```
dic = {1 : 'Primer paso', 2 : 'Segundo paso', 3 : 'Tercer paso'}
print dic_[1]
```

Comment: escribe el código por favor, en lugar de una imagen

Comment: disculpa, aunque es solo el diccionario lo que tengo.
dic = {1:'Primer paso', 2: 'Segundo paso', 3: 'Tercer paso'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo claramente qué puede significar que el usuario tenga que ordenar un diccionario.

Echando mano de mi bola de cristal, veo una posible interpretación de tu pregunta, que sería la siguiente: "Dada una lista que tiene un cierto orden natural, se le presenta la misma al usuario desordenada, y éste debe encontrar cuál era el orden original".

Algo así como lo siguiente. Al usuario se le presenta lo siguiente en pantalla:

```
Pon los siguientes pasos en el orden correcto

1. Echar el huevo batido en la sartén
2. Batir la yema con la clara
3. Esperar que cuaje
4. Buscar un huevo
5. Romper el huevo
6. Degustar tortilla
```

El usuario reconstruye la secuencia correcta, e introduce en el programa la secuencia de números: `4 5 2 1 3 6`. El programa le responde si la respuesta es correcta o no.

Suponiendo que esto sea lo que estabas preguntando, no se ve la necesidad de usar diccionarios ya que estos son inherentemente desordenados (en el sentido de que si los recorres en un bucle tipo `for clave in diccionario:` el orden en que vienen las claves no es predecible). En tu ejemplo usabas enteros como claves, lo cual indica que en realidad estás pensando en una lista.

Una implementación posible (en Python 3) que se comportaría como describí más arriba sería la siguiente:

```
import random

# Esta es la secuencia en el orden correcto que el usuario debe adivinar
pasos = [
    "Buscar un huevo",
    "Romper el huevo",
    "Batir la yema con la clara",
    "Echar el huevo batido en la sartén",
    "Esperar que cuaje",
    "Degustar tortilla"
]

# Sacamos una copia de esa secuencia
copia = list(pasos)

# y la desordenamos aleatoriamente
random.shuffle(copia)

# Ahora mostramos al usuario la secuencia desordenada
print("Pon los siguientes pasos en el orden correcto")
for i, txt in enumerate(copia):
  print("{}. {}".format(i+1, txt))

# Leemos (como cadena) el orden tecleado por el usuario
respuesta = input("Teclea el orden correcto (números separados por espacios): ")
# y convertimos esa cadena a una lista de números
numeros = [int(n) for n in respuesta.split()]

# Usamos esos números para crear una nueva lista, ordenada según la
# elección del usuario
ordenado = [copia[i-1] for i in numeros]

# Verificamos si esta lista es igual a la original
if ordenado == pasos:
  print("Correcto!")
else:
  print("Lo siento, ese no es el orden correcto")
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.
Disculpa por no explicarme bien, es una mala costumbre, pero me entendiste lo que necesitaba hacer, y ahora pude terminarlo, y gracias por la explicación del porque usar mejor una lista que un diccionario.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que estas usando python 2 debido a la sintaxis de tu `print` (yo no lo uso).

Ya para empezar te sugiero que si vas a aprender de cero aprendas python 3 que es más nuevo, porque python 2 desaparecerá su soporte técnico el 2020 si no me equivoco.

Volviendo a tu pregunta:

### Python 2.x

```
import random
dic = {1 : 'Primer paso', 2 : 'Segundo paso', 3 : 'Tercer paso'}
print dic[random.choice(list(dic))]
```

### Python 3.x

```
import random
dic = {1 : 'Primer paso', 2 : 'Segundo paso', 3 : 'Tercer paso'}
print (dic[random.choice(list(dic))])
```

No mucha diferencia entre python 2 y 3 pero bueno.

- `import random`: importa la librería `random`.
- [`random.choice(seq)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences): devuelve un valor aleatorio de la sequencia. Según tengo entendido, esta no puede ser un dictionario.
- `list([iterable])`: convierte la secuencia en una lista. En caso de usar un diccionario, devolverá una lista de las llaves (keys) en esta. Sería algo similar a `.keys()` en un diccionario.

Al combinar todo esto lo que haces es:

1. Convertir el diccionario en una lista de llaves.
2. Adquirir una llave aleatoria.
3. Usar la llave para obtener un valor del diccionario.